# equality of $\dim V_{\lambda_i}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let a square matrix: $$Q = \left(\begin{array}{cccc} A&B\\0&C\end{array}\right)$$
$A,C$ are two square matrices such that $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of $A$ implies $\lambda$ isn't an eigenvalue of $C$ and vice-versa.

I already proved that the set of eigenvalues of $Q$ is a union of the sets of eigenvalues of $A$ and $C$.

Now I need to prove the following: Let $\lambda$, an eigenvalue of $Q$. Let's assume the eigenspace dimension of $\lambda$ is $n$. Then, the eigenspace dimension of the same $\lambda$ for $A$ or $C$ is also $n$.

**A start:**
Let (WLOG) $\lambda$, an eigenvalue of $A$ and let $v$ an eigenvector of $\lambda$. Then we have that $A-\lambda I(v) = 0$.

We look at:
 $$Q-\lambda I(v) = \left(\begin{array}{cccc} A-\lambda I&B\\0&C-\lambda I\end{array}\right)(v) = \left(\begin{array}{cccc} 0&B(v)\\0&C-\lambda I(v)\end{array}\right)$$

I am not so sure how to proceed from here. I think the fact that $\lambda$ isn't an eigenvalue of $C$ should be helpful in this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For clarity of concept, it is worth to note that, by writing $$Q = \left(\begin{array}{cccc} A&B\\0&C\end{array}\right)$$
   $A,C$ are two square matrices, it implies that:

1.a. $Q$ is a linear transformation from one vector space $V$ into itself.

1.b. There $V_1$ and $V_2$ subspaces of $V$ such that $V=V_1\oplus V_2$.

1.c. $A$ is a linear transformation from $V_1$ into $V_1$; $B$ is a linear transformation from $V_2$ into $V_1$ and $C$ is a linear transformation from $V_2$ into $V_2$.

2. I will show a solution using the approach you proposed.

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $Q$.

Let (WLOG) suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. Let $E_\lambda$ be the eigenspace of A for $\lambda$. Then for every $v\in E_\lambda$, we have that $(A-\lambda I)v = 0$.

Note that $v\in V_1$, so $v$ itself can not be an eigenvector of $Q$. Let $i_1$ be the canonical inclusion of $V_1$ into $V$. Then we have $i_1(v)=(v,0)$.

So
 $$(Q-\lambda I)(v,0) = \left(\begin{array}{cc} A-\lambda I&B\\0&C-\lambda I\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}v\\0\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c} (A-\lambda I)v+(B)0\\0v+(C-\lambda I)0\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c} 0\\0 \end{array}\right)$$

So $E_\lambda$, the $\lambda$-eingenspace of A, can be injectively included (by the canonical inclusion of $V_1$ into $V$) into the $\lambda$-eingenspace of $Q$.

Now suppose that $Q$ has an eigenvector (v,w) for the eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then

$$(Q-\lambda I)(v,w) = \left(\begin{array}{cc} A-\lambda I&B\\0&C-\lambda I\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}v\\w\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{c} (A-\lambda I)v+(B)w\\0v+(C-\lambda I)w\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c} 0\\0 \end{array}\right)$$

Since we know that $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue of $C$, we must have $w=0$. And so we have $(B)w=0$. And so $(A-\lambda I)v=0$, which means that $v\in E_\lambda$.

So we have proved that  the $\lambda$-eingenspace of $Q$ is precisely $i_1(E_\lambda)$. That is the $\lambda$-eingenspace of $Q$ is precisely  the image, by the canonical inclusion, of the $\lambda$-eingenspace of $Q$. So they have the same dimension.

Comment: How do you know that $A$ is a linear transformation $V_1\to V_1$ and $C$ is a linear transformation $V_2\to V_2$ such that $V_1 \oplus V_2  = V$?

Comment: @jmiller because: 1. $Q$,  $A$ and $C$  are square matrices, so Q is a linear transformation V→V, A is a linear transformation V1→V1 and C is a linear transformation V2→V2.  2.  $Q$ has $A$ and $C$  forming "its diagonal", so we have  V1⊕V2=V.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to show that $im$ $Q = L_1 + L_2$ and $Q|L_1 = A, Q|L_2 = C$ where $L_1$ and $L_2$ are invariant subspaces of $Q$. Since eigenspace of $\lambda$,  $W_\lambda \subseteq L_1$ $(W_\lambda\subseteq L_2)$ it is obvious that $n = dim$ $W_\lambda$ is eigenspace dimension of $\lambda$ of both $Q$ and $A(C)$.